# Update Table Rows in WatchKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, watchkit

How would I **update my table Rows once the Background query is finished**?

I'm assuming I need to do it in my `Parse` query in my `awakeWithContext`?  I initially set the rows in `willActivate`.

*Will post any extra code/info if needed just let me know, thanks!*

**WatchKit `InterfaceController.m`:**

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];
    // Initialize Parse.
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"xxx"
                  clientKey:@"xxx"];

    // GMT Date from Phone
    NSDate *gmtNow = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"GMT Now: %@", gmtNow);

    // Query Parse
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"na"];

    [query whereKey:@"dateGame" greaterThanOrEqualTo:gmtNow];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSMutableArray *localMatchup = [@[] mutableCopy];

            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                // Add objects to local Arrays
                [localMatchup addObject:[object objectForKey:@"matchup"]];

                // App Group
                NSString *container = @"group.com.me.off";
                NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:container];

                // Matchup
                [defaults setObject:localMatchup forKey:@"KeyMatchup"];
                NSArray *savedMatchup = [defaults objectForKey:@"KeyMatchup"];
                NSLog(@"Default Matchup: %@", savedMatchup);
                savedMatchup = self.matchupArray;
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"Say you went to dispatch");
            });   
        }
    }];

    // App Group
    NSString *container = @"group.com.me.off";
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:container];

    // Matchup
    NSArray *savedMatchup = [defaults objectForKey:@"KeyMatchup"];
    self.matchupArray = savedMatchup;
}

- (void)willActivate {
    [super willActivate];

    // Hide "No Games" Label
    if ([self.matchupArray count] > 0) {

        self.noGamesLabel.hidden = YES;
        self.rowTable.hidden = NO;

        [self.rowTable setNumberOfRows:[self.matchupArray count] withRowType:@"rows"];

        for (NSInteger index = 0; index < [self.timeArray count]; index++) {
            // Matchup
            NSString *matchupString = [self.matchupArray objectAtIndex:index];
            RowController *controller = [self.rowTable rowControllerAtIndex:index];
            [controller.matchupLabel setText:matchupString];
        }
    }
    // Show "No Games" Label
    else {
        self.rowTable.hidden = YES;
        self.noGamesLabel.hidden = NO;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new method that is called at the end of your `PFQuery`'s callback and in the `willActivate` method, such as:

```
- (void)populateTable {
    // Hide "No Games" Label
    if ([self.matchupArray count] > 0) {

        self.noGamesLabel.hidden = YES;
        self.rowTable.hidden = NO;

        [self.rowTable setNumberOfRows:[self.matchupArray count] withRowType:@"rows"];

        for (NSInteger index = 0; index < [self.matchupArray count]; index++) {
            // Matchup
            NSString *matchupString = [self.matchupArray objectAtIndex:index];
            RowController *controller = [self.rowTable rowControllerAtIndex:index];
            [controller.matchupLabel setText:matchupString];
        }
    }
    // Show "No Games" Label
    else {
        self.rowTable.hidden = YES;
        self.noGamesLabel.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

In here you may wish to also show a label to tell the user when the data is being refreshed.

The end of the callback also looks like it should be:

```
// Matchup
[defaults setObject:localMatchup forKey:@"KeyMatchup"];
NSLog(@"Default Matchup: %@", localMatchup);
self.matchupArray = localMatchup;
[self populateTable];
```

Comment: Do that inside my `PFQuery` with the same exact code I'm using in my `willActivate`, or are you saying something different?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I had missed that part the code. What you may wish to do is set `matchupArray` at the end of the query callback and create a new `populateTable` (or similar) method. Copy/paste your current `willActivate` body in to the new method and call that from the `willActivate` method

Comment: Will it work calling it from the `willActivate` method since `willActivate` will already have run before the background query finishes?

Comment: It will obviously not have the latest data (as you point out), but it will have data loaded via `NSUserDefaults`. Maybe you could create a new property to track if the data is being reloaded and hide/show a label based on if the query has finished?

Comment: Yeah because the problem is coming when the Watch extension runs, there is nothing stored in the `NSUserDefaults` yet, so when the table loads there is not going to be anything in it (since the query hasn't run yet).  So the background query needs to run, then update the UI.

Comment: I've updated my answer to try and give you a bit of an idea. Hopefully it makes sense

Comment: Thanks for adding that code.  Where are you calling `populateTable`? And I'm not understanding the part where you put "The end of the callback also looks like it should be", I'm not following you on that part can you specify a little more if its a suggestion or if its something I need to do or where you're saying it goes?

Comment: Your `awakeWithContext:` method does not seem to set the value of `matchupArray`, so the updated data would be available for the table. I have updated the code to fix a typo. It should be calling `[self populateTable`], not `[self localMatchup]`

Comment: Gotcha, the only other 2 things I'm wondering is: 1- why you omitted the line `NSArray *savedMatchup = [defaults objectForKey:@"KeyMatchup"];` and 2- why you used `self.matchupArray = localMatchup;` instead of `savedMatchup = self.matchupArray;`?

Comment: Your submitted code saves `localMatchup` in to `defaults`, so there's no need to load it back out and put in to `savedMatchup`. `savedMatchup` is then being assigned to `self.matchupArray`, which is only set at the end of your `awakeWithContext:` method, likely before the query has finished. Surely you would want to be keeping a copy of `localMatchup` for your table by using `self.matchupArray`?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying you're code, and it is working in terms of refreshing the table and giving me the right amount of rows.  What isn't working is that it is just showing the placeholder text "Matchup" in each row except the actual matchup that was saved via the PFQuery.  I know all the outlets are hooked up and the PFQuery is running fine, so thats why I'm trying to figure out why something is breaking down in the process somewhere

Comment: For whatever reason, inside `populateTable`, the code never runs after `for (NSInteger index = 0; index < [self.timeArray count]; index++) {` into getting and setting the text.  Like it will never run the line `[controller.matchupLabel setText:matchupString];` for some reason... any ideas?

Comment: Then I changed the line to `        for (NSInteger index = 0; index < [self.matchupArray count]; index++) {' and that worked in terms of getting it to run the setting and getting lines like `[controller.matchupLabel setText:matchupString];`, but the only problem was that the rows didn't even show up this time and populate with even the placeholder text.

Comment: I may be wrong, but don't you have to call `setHidden`, rather than assigning to the `hidden` property with `WKInterfaceController`'s? All my WatchKit stuff has been done in Swift so I'm not sure if I've missed something or it's different in Objective-C?